# Room Migration failed while query for creating FTS table

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-room

I am trying to work on a FTS4 . I already have a table company for which full text search has to be enabled but facing issues.

```
database.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companyFts` USING FTS4(`company`, content = `company`)");
```

Above is the query inside ROOM Migration but it is giving following error

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) statement aborts at 28: [CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `companyFts` USING FTS4(`company`, content = `company`)] unrecognized parameter: content = `company`
```

[image]

Comment: I think that (content = company) should be enclosed in a whole.

Comment: @RishavChudal as per your suggestion changed it, but now red error moves to the starting of newly added round bracket